# Create ellipse mask over image matrix

Tags: matlab

Have been trying to draw my ellipse over a 2D image with imellipse in the following code. Is there a way to create the ellipse mask without calling figure or imellipse? Removing the call for figure would cause an error, though I need to make sure that the ellipse lies in a 2D matrix of size of largestAreaI.

```
laFig = figure();
imshow(largestAreaI);
lAEllipse = imellipse(gca, [xLA yLA hortLA hortLA]);

lAMask=lAEllipse.createMask();
close(laFig);

lAMask=imrotate(lAMask, statsLA.Orientation,'crop');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are after a binary mask to multiply to your image in the shape of an ellipse?

```
X0=0; %Coordinate X
Y0=0; %Coordinate Y
l=25; %Length
w=15; %Width
phi=45; %Degree you want to rotate
[X Y] = meshgrid(-50:50,-50:50); %make a meshgrid: use the size of your image instead
ellipse = ((X-X0)/l).^2+((Y-Y0)/w).^2<=1; %Your Binary Mask which you multiply to your image, but make sure you change the size of your mesh-grid
RotateEllipse = imrotate(ellipse,phi);
```

To make sure that the ellipse lies in boundary, simply do something like:

`X0 + l` and `X0 -l` must be within the max and min of your image in the X direction and similarly `Y0 + w` and `Y0 - w` must be within the max and min of your image in the Y direction.

```
 if X0-l < 1 | X0 + l > size(image,2) | Y0-w < 1 | Y0 + w > size(image,1)
 ellipse has elements outside image
 end

imagesc(RotateEllipse);
```

[image: result looks like:]

Rotate causes some rough edges due to interpolation issues, trying the 'bicubic' option:

```
RotateEllipse = imrotate(ellipse,phi,'bicubic');
```

[image: Bicubic Option]

Comment: thanks very much! realised that the length and width have to be halved (like radius) for the equation. otherwise works great!

Comment: @GameOfThrows One other way to get rid of using `imrotate` (and potential bad interpolation) is to simply create your ellipse at the origin, then after you create your meshgrid of X,Y points, you can rotate and shift those points *before* determining if they are inside the ellipse.